# using 3 layouts on same gsp page

Tags: grails, layout

this is edit of my question that was first how to apply 2 layouts in the same gsp page but now i got problem with 3 layouts :) :

I am fairly new to all that css and layout stuff and i'm using grails 2.0 version
i have the following moduls in my problem:
1. main.gsp layout which basically have a nice header with company logo for all pages.
2. mainTabPanle.gsp layouts which basically contain some main tabs all pages should have
3. reportTab.gsp layout which basically contain nice report tabs and short javascript code to manipulate chosen tab color that all reports gsp pages should have.

what i am trying to do is to use this reportTab layout in all the reports gsp pages.

so this is what i got so far:

main.gsp:

```
<!doctype html>  
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}"type="text/css">
<g:layoutHead/>
<r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body style="height:100%">
<div>some nice header in here </div>
<g:layoutBody/>
<r:layoutResources />
</body>
</html>
```

mainTabPanle.gsp (also located in layout folder)

```
<g:applyLayout name="main">    
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head>
<g:layoutHead/>
<r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>
<div>some main tabs here </div> 
<g:layoutBody/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//script to manipulate main tabs    
</script>
<r:layoutResources />
</body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

reportTabPanel.gsp:

```
<g:applyLayout name="mainTabPanel">    
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head>
<g:layoutHead/>
<r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>
<div>some reports tab panel </div>  
<g:layoutBody/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//some script to manipulate report tab item
</script>
<r:layoutResources />
</body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

and now im using in moneyreport.gsp header the following line:

```
<meta name="layout" content="reportTabPanel" />
```

what i want to see is the nice header and the maintabsPanel and the reportTabPanel but all i see is the body of moneyreport.gsp

the weird thing is that if i use this:

```
<meta name="layout" content="mainTabPanel" />
```

inside moneyreport.gsp i see mainTab and the body of moneyreport.gsp as expected.

what am i doing wrong? i cannot use 3 layout on the same page?

thanks for your help guys ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply 2 layouts on the same page. In order to apply a different layout in a layout file, you need to use the applyLayout tag. Your reportTab should be something like this:

```
<g:applyLayout name="main">    
<!doctype html>  
<head>
<g:layoutHead/>
<r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>
<div> some nice tabs here </div>
<g:layoutBody/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
few line script handling chosen tab color in here
</script>
<r:layoutResources />
</body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

Comment: anju i edit my question .... basically what you said worked fine.than i tried to use the same logic to apply 3 layouts and it fail. i wonder if you can fix me again. thanks in advance!

Comment: @user511875: You can use any number of layouts on the same page. The only issue that I see in the code that you have posted is a typo in the file name that you have mentioned (it's written mainTabPanle instead of mainTabPanel). I have tested the code that you have posted and it is working fine

Comment: really?!?!?! you tested my code and its working fine??? if this is the case its great news ... unfortunately i have to put this aside now too much things to achieve first here at work. but judging from before i am almost sure what you said is true so many thanks anju for your help and for the time you put to help me out. once i get some free time to keep with this project i will post another reply that it is working :) thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using templates because you can use as many as you want. I have this main HTML where I want to include different templates, like a menu and a generic content page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>
    <g:layoutTitle default="Loto Tasks"/>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>

<!-- Including menu -->
<g:render template="/templates/menu" />

<!-- Including generic content page --> 
<g:render template="/templates/genericcontent" />

<g:layoutBody/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a package named `templates` inside a `views` package, and inside `templates` I have two files, `_menu.gsp` and `_genericcontent.gsp`. The `_genericcontent.gsp` file looks like the following simple code. I could see that this is a little confusing if I insert a `<head>` with imports to other files, but you can import in the main file and it works:

**_genericcontent.gsp**

```
<div id="mainSearchPanel" class="searchPanel">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="searchPanelCloseBtn" onclick="closeSearchPanel()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Filter panel here</a>
</div>

<div id="search-icon" class="animate__animated animate__heartBeat animate__infinite animate__slower">
    <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first thanks for your reply Anuj !

it kind of work but in a wrong way cuz i was getting weird html source:
i was getting 2 headers and 2 body tags so basically grails just copy paste all the layout
together and that wasn't good html page even that the browser display it right!

i found what i needed and that is simply using templates!
for example i have file called "_mainHeader.gsp" which look like this:

```
<!-- this is my main header for all gsp pages -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>IntentIQ Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}"type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir:'images/myImg',file:'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
```

and from all pages i can use those lines like for example in page1.gsp:

```
<g:render template="/templates/mainHeader" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> this is page1 with header from mainHeader.gsp template </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pay attention for who ever who read this to:
1.temmplate file name are with '_' character
2.the closing body tag in "page1.gsp" is closing the body tag started at "_mainHeader.gsp" file.

so basically this tempaltes stuff is kind of copy paste of parts of gsp pages and its working great!
thanks for your reply never the less!

Comment: Well, the solution that you have provided would work no doubt, but it isn't as clean as you would want it to be. The reason that you were getting weird html in the earlier solution was that the applyLayout tag wasn't closed. Please see my edit.